# Are there english words for a person who sincerely thinks of himself as an expert but in reality (by common standards) is not?

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there english words for a person who sincerely thinks of him as an expert but in reality (by common standards) is not?

Source: Recently, in my native place, a very popular movie actor (let us say his name is extrem) started a music band and held a live show during a government sponsored program which was widely criticized and made fun of. Nowadays, if someone claims to be something he is not, the media refers to it as extremism jokingly.

Comment: That person is a *fool*, in common parlance.

Comment: "wannabe", "poser", a "legend-in-his-own-mind" are a few examples that might fit your description

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would call such a person a dilettante -- one "whose interest in an art or in an area of knowledge is not very deep or serious."

Answer (score 0):

It is nowadays a bit dated to call someone a ***a big head***, but that probably sums up what you are looking for, better than anything.